# How to create a polar bar plot in R with a quarter circle shape using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently read an article and was interested in a particular polar bar plot figure:
[image]

I wanted to try drawing it using ggplot in R, so I simulated a dataframe. However, after several attempts, I was only able to draw a complete circular polar bar plot instead of a quarter circle polar bar plot as intended.

This is my R code:

```
library(ggplot2)

#create a dataframe
data = data.frame(angle=sample(0:90, size = 15, replace = FALSE), cell=sample(1:30, size = 15, replace =TRUE))
data

#create polar bar plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = angle, y = cell, fill = factor(angle))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 3) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_polar(start = 0, direction = 1)
```

This is the resulting figure:

[image]

In the simulated dataframe, my angle values range from 0-90. How can I adjust it to only show a quarter polar plot like the example figure? If you can kindly assist me in solving this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It doesn't look as if this is currently easy to do, but it seems to be on the development list for ggplot2... https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/5028.

Answer (score 3):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to stick with cartesian coordinates and use `ggforce::geom_arc_bar`. Tricky part is getting the grid lines for which I use `ggforce::geom_arc` and computing the positions for the rays or segments as well as for the labels for which I use some math (see [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  angle = sample(0:90, size = 15, replace = FALSE),
  cell = sample(1:30, size = 15, replace = TRUE)
)

alpha <- pi / 6
# Maximum radius to draw grid lines, set limits ...
# I set it equal to the maximum value.
max_r <- max(data$cell)
bar_width <- 5
padding_limits <- 2
nudge_labels <- 1.5

ggplot(data) +
  # Grid lines
  geom_arc(
    data = data.frame(
      start = 0,
      end = .5 * pi,
      r = seq(0, max_r, 5)
    ),
    aes(
      x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = r,
      start = start, end = end,
      linetype = r == max_r
    ),
  ) +
  # Axes
  annotate(
    geom = "segment", x = 0, y = 0,
    xend = max_r * cos(alpha * c(0, 3)),
    yend = max_r * sin(alpha * c(0, 3)),
  ) +
  # Dashed rays from origin
  annotate(
    geom = "segment", x = 0, y = 0,
    xend = max_r * cos(alpha * c(1, 2)),
    yend = max_r * sin(alpha * c(1, 2)),
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  # Arc labels
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = (max_r + nudge_labels) * cos(alpha * 0:3),
    y = (max_r + nudge_labels) * sin(alpha * 0:3),
    label = paste0(30 * 0:3, "°") # 30 = 30 degrees
  ) +
  # Bars.
  geom_arc_bar(aes(
    x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = cell,
    start = (angle - bar_width / 2) / 180 * pi,
    end = (angle + bar_width / 2) / 180 * pi,
    fill = factor(angle)
  ), position = "identity") +
  # Grid - linetypes - solid for the outer
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c("FALSE" = "dashed", "TRUE" = "solid"),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  coord_equal(
    xlim = c(0, max_r + padding_limits),
    ylim = c(0, max_r + padding_limits),
    expand = FALSE, clip = "off"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: artistic indeed